# error: incompatible types: NullPointerException cannot be converted to Throwable

Tags: nullpointerexception

I am trying to handle the NullPointerException. I am getting the following error after executing the .class file

```
NullPointerException.java:11: error: incompatible types: NullPointerException cannot be converted to Throwable
        catch(NullPointerException e)
```

The code for the exception handling is

I caught the exception successfully when I write either `catch(Exception e)` or `catch(Throwable e)`
but writing `catch(NullPointerException e)` in code generating error. What could be the reason?

EDIT 1:
Code is as follows:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class NullPointerException
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        String s=null;
        try
        {     
            System.out.println(s.length());//NullPointerException
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            System.out.println("You are trying to print the null value of string causing ");
        } 

         System.out.println("rest of the code...");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code in the question as well, only then you could get help from the community.

Comment: Please post your code. I suspect it has to do with the declared exceptions of your try block.

Comment: This link: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR08-J.+Do+not+catch+NullPointerException+or+any+of+its+ancestors might help